# executeUpdate() does not add string variables

Tags: java, database

I have created such statement:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO ZMONES (ID, PAVADINIMAS, SLAPTAZODIS) VALUES("
    +sum+" ,"+a+", "+b+")";
```

where variable sum is an integer ID in the database's table and a and b are two string values that are to be added. I am executing this statement as such: `stmt.executeUpdate(query);`

However this error pops out:

> Column 'PERSON' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appers
>   within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join
>   specification or appears in a having clause and is not in the GROUP BY
>   list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE statement then 'PERSON' is
>   not a column in the target table.

I do understand that Java interprets it as a column's name, I do not however, understand why this happens? I have searched for in this in stackoverflow and most questions deal with text and not string variables.

Comment: system out `query ` and execute it in your db client, i bet your strings are not properly quoted.

Answer (score 4):

The error that you ran into can be corrected easily as follows (assuming `sum` is a number):

```
String query = "INSERT INTO ZMONES (ID, PAVADINIMAS, SLAPTAZODIS) VALUES("
    +sum+" ,'"+escape(a)+"', '"+escape(b)+"')";
```

Where `escape(String)` is the following method:

```
public String escape(String string) {
    // This works in most databases, although some require you to escape apostrophes via \'
    return string == null ? null : string.replace("'", "''");
}
```

#### A note on SQL injection

But please! Don't do that. Use a `PreparedStatement` and proper bind variables instead of concatenating your input into your SQL statements. Why?

- Because of [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)
- Because of [performance considerations](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/bind-parameters)

Here's how:

```
try (PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO ZMONES (ID, PAVADINIMAS, SLAPTAZODIS) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
    s.setInt(1, sum);
    s.setString(2, a);
    s.setString(3, b);
    s.executeQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround strings with quotation marks:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO ZMONES (ID, PAVADINIMAS, SLAPTAZODIS) VALUES("+sum+", '"+a+"', '"+b+"')";
```

Comment: Note that this way of working leaves you open the SQL Injection attacks. Refer to Lucas' answer for a way around this.